# What kind of JUnit test can you do with this bit of code?

Tags: java, junit

```
public static void sql() {
    String url = "jdbc:msql://carthage.imaginary.com/ora";
    Connection con = null;

    try {
      String driver = "com.imaginary.sql.msql.MsqlDriver";

      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Failed to load mSQL driver.");
      return;
    }
    try {
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "borg", "");
      Statement select = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet result = select
          .executeQuery("SELECT test_id, test_val FROM test");

      System.out.println("Got results:");
      while (result.next()) { // process results one row at a time
        int key = result.getInt(1);
        String val = result.getString(2);

        System.out.println("key = " + key);
        System.out.println("val = " + val);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (con != null) {
        try {
          con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have to do some tests with Junit for a bunch of SQL methods and I have no idea what I could do with this bit of code. I know how to use assert and expected exception, but those are useless here.

Comment: Can you refactor any of this into smaller units of work?  By that, I mean different methods (one to connect, one to get the results, one to print results, etc). If you can, then you can certainly write tests to test each individual piece of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly i would re-factor the code into two part.

```
1 .create connection

2. Get connection object and do operation.
```

you are combining both in your code.

i would do test cases as below

firstly write a junit class for testing connection.

```
Class GenericDAO
public static Connection getConnection(){

   do your sql steps and return connection object

}
```

and your test class should be

```
public class TestConnection {

   public void testConnection(){
    Connection con = GenericDAO.getConnection();

   assert here for not null
   Assert.assertForNotNull(con );
   }

add test cases for other boundary condition

}
```

later you can write individual test cases other table sql query

for test table

```
public class TestDAO
      //either you pass conection object or inherit from parent class
      public String retrieveResults(){
       do opertaion here

    }
  }
```

and you will have separate junit for this

```
class TestDAOTest{

   public void testForResults(){

    String str = testDAO.retreiveResults();

    do assertrtion as per your wise

   assert for null, or specific string, negative test cases etc. Note , each can be a separate test cases, by this we are covering boundary conditions

   }

}
```

lastly, you can combine the tests into test-suite, and run together

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you write some test cases. And then you implemente the methods that are cases needed(refactor this bit of code into methods).

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not return anything, so I think this your method is just to play around with?
Normally methods in your DAO will return , insert, update or delete values. These are things you can test.